# error model exists, but doesn't declare class

Tags: php, codeigniter

The error: (application\models/projects/It_project_companies.php exists, but doesn't declare class It_project_companies), occurs when I try saving a project. I am loading the model in the save method from controller:

```
public function addProject()
{
    $input = $this->input->post(null, true);

    if ($this->validateFields($input)) {
        $this->load->model('projects/it_projects_notifiers');
        $this->load->model('projects/it_project_companies'); //my model

        $projectData = [
            'title' => $input['project_subject'],
            'description' => $input['project_details'],
            'creator' => $_SESSION['UserID'],
            'affected' => $input['affected_id'],
            'assignee' => $input['project_responsible'],
            'priority' => $input['project_priority'],
            'type' => $input['project_type'],
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'company' => $input['project_companies'],//$project_company,
            'start_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['project_start_date'])),
            'end_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['project_end_date'])),
            'estimated' => ($input['project_estimated_days'] * 24 + $input['project_estimated_hours']),
        ];

        if ($this->db->insert('it_projects', $projectData)) {
            $projectID = $this->db->insert_id();

            $this->it_project_companies->addCompanies($projectID, $input['project_companies']);

            $this->it_projects_notifiers->add_notifiers_affected($projectID, $input['affected_id']);

            $this->it_projects_notifiers->add_notifiers($projectID, $input['project_notifiers']);

            // add files ...
            $this->uploadFiles($_FILES, $projectID);

            $this->load->model('projects/it_projects_notifications');
            $this->it_projects_notifications->send_notifications('new_project', 0, $projectID, $_FILES);
        }
    }
}
```

and addCompanies method from model:

```
    class It_project_companies extends \My_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addCompanies($projectID, $companyIDs) {
        foreach ($companyIDs as $companyID) {
            $projectCompanyData = [
                'project_id' => $projectID,
                'company_id' => $companyID,
            ];
            $this->db->insert('it_project_companies', $projectCompanyData);
        }
    }
}
```

I must add that currently I didn't made the queries to join the needed tables etc...because I am not sure how to make them and the error still occurred when I had the queries, probably written wrong...

Comment: "The error occurs" - which error? Can you share it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: I have updated the post with the included error. I don't know how to solve the problem because I don't know where it comes from. I was thinking maybe is something wrong in how I've loaded de model, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
## Your model should look like this ##

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class It_project_companies extends CI_Model
{
    public function addCompanies($projectID, $companyIDs){}
}

## but since you are extending ##
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class It_project_companies extends My_Model
    {
        public function addCompanies($projectID, $companyIDs){}
    }
```

I don't know why you had a '/' before My_Model

```
## My_Model ##
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
 public function __construct(){}
}
```

Comment: The ide added '/' , if I removed it, would appear 'use My_Model', but since I deleted the namespace, works ok.  My class looks like the one you wrote (## but since you are extending ##).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to remove the namespace, because I don't have autoload in composer.json. I don't know if it's a good approach to load the model with `$this->load->model()`, or I should Autoload Classes With Composer.